# Prolog pattern matching function with n arguments

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

I want to know how to do a pattern matching of a function that can take n arguments in prolog for example :
cons(1,2) should return [1,2],cons (1,2,3) should return [1,2,3]and(cons(1,2,3,....,n)) returns [1,2,3,....,n]
so cons can have as many arguments as it wants 
and the only thing i could think if is 
match(cons(A,B),[A,B]).but that just works with 2 arguments , so i want to generalize it for n arguments .

Comment: Prolog doesn't have functions. It has *predicates*. You cannot have a *predicate* with a variable number of parameters. However, if you want to write `match(cons(...), List)`, then to solve your problem, you can very simply use `=../2`. It's a one-liner. You can look it up in the Prolog documentation.

Comment: i will look it up thanks

Comment: @lurker Or compound_name_arguments/3 to cover the arity zero-case.